# multiple conditions and assignment in php

Tags: php

An easy question about how php behaves:

getColor is a function of class Circle which returns  either false or an object with the color as an attribute. If I do:

```
$res=$circle->getColor();
if ($res && $res->color=='white')
{
    echo "ok";
 } else {
    echo "no";
 }
```

I get "ok", but if I do

```
if ($res=$circle->getColor() && $res->color=='white')
{
    echo "ok";
 } else {
    echo "no";
 }
```

I get "no". Why? I thought first condition is executed first. Isn't it?

Comment: You really shouldn't do it this way, as your logic is very confusing.  However, I am very curious as to why you see the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Something tells me the parser is misinterpreting. Try being a bit more explicit using parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).  Because `&&` has higher precedence than `=` PHP is effective seeing this:

```
if ($res = ($circle->getColor() && $res->color=='white'))
```

In order to get the behavior you want, you should parenthesize the first condition:

```
if (($res = $circle->getColor()) && $res->color == 'white')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have it bookmarked because I never remember this stuff.  I commit parentheses abuse instead.